# Gulp 4 - Azure Website

Tags: node.js, azure, gulp, azure-web-app-service

I have a Node.js website I am trying to deploy to Windows Azure. This website requires that I run gulp in order to get the html minified, etc. In an attempt to do that, I've added the following to my `deploy.sh` file:

```
if [ -e "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET/gulpfile.js" ]; then
    echo "Running gulp tasks"
    cd "$DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
    eval './node_modules/.bin/gulp'
    exitWithMessageOnError "gulp failed"
    cd -> /dev/null
fi
```

My challenge is, my gulpfile was created locally using Gulp 4. From what I can tell, that version isn't supported. This is based on the fact that in my npm-debug.log file, I see the following:

```
516 error notarget No compatible version found: gulp@'github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0'
516 error notarget Valid install targets:
516 error notarget ["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.7","0.0.8","0.0.9","0.1.0","0.2.0","1.0.0","1.1.0","1.2.0","1.2.1","2.0.0","2.0.1","2.1.0","2.2.0","2.3.0","2.4.0","2.4.1","2.6.0","2.6.1","2.7.0","3.0.0","3.1.1","3.1.2","3.1.3","3.1.4","3.2.0","3.2.1","3.2.2","3.2.3","3.2.4","3.2.5","3.3.0","3.3.1","3.3.2","3.3.4","3.4.0","3.5.0","3.5.1","3.5.2","3.5.5","3.5.6","3.6.0","3.6.1","3.6.2","3.7.0","3.8.0","3.8.1","3.8.2","3.8.3","3.8.4","3.8.5","3.8.6","3.8.7","3.8.8","3.8.9","3.8.10","3.8.11","3.9.0","3.9.1"]
516 error notarget
```

However, in my package.json file, I've set the Node engine to

```
"engines": {
  "node": "~5.3.0"
},
```

which is supported and I believe is the only requirement for Gulp 4. What am I missing?

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**

Complete package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/server.js"
  },
  "description": "My Website",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~5.3.0",
    "npm": "3.3.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.5.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-exec": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "express-livereload": "0.0.24",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: The latest version of gulp is 3.9.1 according to the github and npm. Where did you find a v4?

Comment: @ShanShan The latest version on the master branch is 3.9.1 however there is also a [4.0 branch](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/4.0)

Comment: I see. How did you install it in the first place? I tried `gulp@next` and `gulp@4.0` but **no version  found**.

Comment: @ShanShan In the `devDependencies` section of my "package.json" file, I have: `"gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",`

Comment: @ShanShan Gulp 4.0 seems pretty far along (over 1 year now). I really wanted to use the ES 6 goodness and parallel and series tasks to help dictate control flow better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your log:

> error notarget No compatible version found:
>   gulp@'github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0'

It seems you have used a low version of npm to install your dependencies.

And you do not specify the npm version in your `package.json` file, which will make the Azure Web app to use the default npm version 2.11.2.

So add the npm version in "engines" closure, and here is my test 'package.json':

```
 {
    "engines": {
      "node": "~5.3.0",
      "npm": "3.3.12"
    },
    "dependencies":{
        "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either. Basically it ends with an error that says `511 error git clone git@github.com:github:gulpjs/gulp    is not a valid repository name`. It's still not letting me get the 4.0 version of Gulp.

Comment: Hi, @JQueryMobile, as shown in my update, i used the `package.json` content to deploy to Azure, and the deployment task ran very well. Were you using Azure Web App, and will you please provide the `package.json` content for us to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @gary-liu-msft - I have updated the question and included the entire `package.json` file. I am using an Azure Web App.

Comment: I tested in your package.json file, and it worked fine on my side. You can try to use a new Web App with a `Node JS Empty Web App` template, and  try to finish your deployment task again

Comment: So, I did that as well. However, did you also have a ".deployment" file? My version has: ```[config]
command = bash deploy.sh
project = dist
``` The problem isn't in the package, its when the deploy.sh file gets ran using the first block of code in my question.

Comment: In fact, I just logged into my sites scm, navigated to ~/home/site/wwwroot/ and ran `npm install` manually just to see what would happen. In the process, I received the error mentioned in my question.

Comment: OK, actually, the npm version in scm env is the default version which is 2.11.2, and the package.json will only impact the npm version in deployment tasks. So you may try to modify the `package.Json` in your original repository, then deploy to Azure via Git.

Comment: @gary-liu-msft - What do you mean by modify the `package.json` in the repository? What specifically should I change? In my opinion, the `package.json` settings look correct. For that reason, I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: You mentioned you installed the dependencies in the kudu console site, but in this way, you still run in a low version of npm. only in deployment task, we can specify the npm version we configured in `package.json` in original repository

Comment: So, when I look in the log file, I see: ```Selected node.js version 5.3.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Selected npm version 3.3.12```. That's what I need to run gulp 4 correct? So why would I still be getting the error?

Comment: When I got the same error, I saw there was the `selected npm version` sentence in the log, but under the sentence, the log recorded that it still use the low version, can you find any relative sentence?

Comment: You also can try to modify `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` of APP Setting to specify the node version of web site. refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/ for more